# Maximum likelihood for Poisson, having trouble with frequency table

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

this one has an answer in the back of the book, but I cannot understand it really.

> > For the Major League Baseball season from 1950 through 2008, there were fifty-nine nine-innings games in which one of the teams did not manage to get a hit. The data in the table give the number of no-hitters per season over this period. Assume that the data follow a Poisson distribution,
> >
> > a) Estimate $\lambda$ and compare the observed and expected frequencies.

$$P_X(k;\lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \; \quad k=0,1,2,...$$

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Number of No-Hitters}& \text{Frequency} \\ \hline
 0& 6\\ \hline
 1& 19\\ \hline
 2& 12\\ \hline
 3& 13\\ \hline
 4& 9\\ \hline
\end{array}

Now I worked out the maximum likelihood to be 
$$\lambda = \frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}k_i}{n}$$

I believe that is correct, but what I do not understand comparing the observed and expected frequencies, the book's is their answer as below:

First it has the expected value worked out based on the observed values. 
$\lambda = [0(6) + 1(19) + 2(12) + 3(13) + 4(9)]/59 = 2.00$

This is probably very simple, but I'm not seeing it, how did he get the third column of the table below?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Number of No-Hitters}& \text{Observed Freq.}& \text{Expected Freq.} \\ \hline
 0& 6 & 8.0\\ \hline
 1& 19 & 16.0\\ \hline
 2& 12 & 16.0\\ \hline
 3& 13 & 10.6\\ \hline
 4& 9 & 8.4\\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You then plug in the estimated value of $\lambda$ into the PMF to get the prediction for the probabilities, then multiply that by $n$ to get the prediction for the frequencies. So for example $59 \cdot e^{-2} 2^0/0!$ is about $8$, which is the predicted frequency of $0$. Presumably all the individual frequencies shouldn't be too far apart from the data; if they are, then your speculation that the underlying distribution was Poisson was probably wrong.

Comment: Hi @Ian that makes sense, however, that now means that my estimator is wrong, because my equation for my estimator is basically [0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4]/59. Which is not exactly the same as theirs. This is my confusion. Shouldn't mine be something like $\lambda = \frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}\times f_i}{n}$ where $f_i= frequency_{k_i}$ ? Or am I missing something?